# How to override step-navigator in checkout?

Tags: checkout, javascript, onepage-checkout, overrides

I need to override/extend the step-navigator.js with the function "isProcessed" but that link [How to extend js class/method of checkout model class in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92396/how-to-extend-js-class-method-of-checkout-model-class-in-magento-2)
doesn't work.
Magento can't find the pluggin.js.

Comment: can you share your code?