# Magento 2 : How Can I Override Step-Navigator File From Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, knockoutjs

I want to override step-navigator js file. I had followed this method [How to extend js class/method of checkout model class in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92396/how-to-extend-js-class-method-of-checkout-model-class-in-magento-2) but it didn't work. any help.

I want to override this method.

```
navigateTo: function (code, scrollToElementId) {

    },
```

My code in require js file

```
var config = {
'config': {
'mixins': {
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
        'Av_ShoppingCart/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin': true
    },
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
        'Av_ShoppingCart/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin': true
    },
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator': {
            'Av_ShoppingCart/js/model/step-navigator': true
     }
}
```

}

My code of customizing step-navigator file

```
define(function () {
'use strict';

return function (target) { 
    var navigateTo = target.navigateTo;
    target.navigateTo = function(code, scrollToElementId) {

        alert("safasfaf");

        var result = navigateTo.apply(this, arguments);
        // //after method call
        return  result;
    };
    return target.
};
```

});

Comment: Can you tell me what issue you are facing?

Comment: It's not showing me the alert when i click on one of the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

To overide step navigator:
create a requirejs-config.js file under view/frontend/web
Add the following code in your requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator": 
"Av_ShoppingCart/js/model/step-navigator",
        }
    }
};
```

copy the Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator.js from the core and add it in your module Av_ShoppingCart/js/model/step-navigator.js.